What is もの in 持ってるって今まで知らなかったものなら?
I have doubts with もの in this sentence 持ってるって今まで知らなかったものなら. There are two possible interpretations for this もの:

Object for 持ってる

Part of ものなら construction


I think two is likely because the hidden object for 持ってる is 自由. So this means the verb that is placed before ものなら doesn't have to be in potential form?


This もの is the object of 持ってる:

持ってるって今まで知らなかったものならなおさら！
That's more true if it's something you didn't know you already have!

However, I'm not sure what this もの actually refers to:

At least, it's not 自由 because 自由 is something that has been deprived (and thus doesn't exist) in this context.
It's not 生きる権利 for the same reason.
It might be 生きたいと思う意思. If so, the sentence means "If you didn't know you have the will to live, it proves you have the will to live!" She might be trying to say that everyone has the will to live regardless of their awareness of it, but such a logic seems a bit presumptuous to me...
It may be something not mentioned on this page. See the previous context.

The ものなら construction you mentioned is used to make an unlikely hypothesis about the future, and it's usually used with a potential form (e.g. やれるものなら) or a volitional form (e.g. 言おうものなら).

Thanks. It looks like yet another example of 倒置. Both なら-ending clauses modify 生きる権利がなかったとしても生きたいと思う意思はあるでしょ, right? I think your third option 生きたいと思う意思 is most likely. For context, she freed all seals from a zoo and she tries to justify why it is the right thing to do.
